# Is there a way to use an if statement in an array element?

Tags: arrays, batch-file, if-statement

So I'm setting up random generation of worlds in batch. For this, I need to put an if statement into an array. However, it does not seem to recognize that I'm trying to put a variable inside a variable.

So far, I've tried using !, %%, and % for the variables. I also tried removing the if statements, and although the error stopped, the numbers still got below 0 and above 15.

This is the code I currently have. i believe that the problem is in the 2 if statements on lines 8 and 9, as without them

```
echo Generating biomes...
rem 0x 0y
set /A biomenum0x0y = %RANDOM% * 16 / 32768 + 1
rem The rest!
for %%x in (neg1 0 1) do (
   for %%y in (neg1 0 1) do (
      set /A nextbiomenum = !RANDOM! * 4 / 32768 - 1, biomenum[%%x][%%y] = biomenum[0][0] + nextbiomenum %% 2
      if %%biomenum[%x%][%y%]%% LSS 0 set %%biomenum[%x%][%y%]%% EQU "0"
      if %%biomenum[%x%][%y%]%% GTR 15 set %%biomenum[%x%][%y%]%% EQU "15" 
   )
)
echo %biomenum[neg1][neg1]% is the biome for -1,-1
echo %biomenum[neg1][0]% is the biome for -1, 0
echo %biomenum[neg1][1]% is the biome for -1, 1
echo %biomenum[0][neg1]% is the biome for 0, -1
echo %biomenum[0][0]% is the biome for 0, 0 -the starting chunk-
echo %biomenum[0][1]% is the biome for 0, 1
echo %biomenum[1][neg1]% is the biome for 1, -1
echo %biomenum[1][0]% is the biome for 1, 0
echo %biomenum[1][1]% is the biome for 1, 1
```

What it should be doing is keeping the number between 0 and 15, however sometimes it goes to -1 and 16. It also prints out `Environment variable %biomenum[][]% EQU "15"  not defined` 9 times.

Comment: Like `if !biomenum[%x%][%y%]! lss 0 set "!biomenum[%x%][%y%]!=0"` (with [dleayed expansion](https://sste.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) enabled, of course, as otherwise, the `!` are not recognised)

Comment: There are _not_ such `%x%` and `%y%` variables; there are `%%x` and `%%y` FOR command replaceable parameters... The array elements are called `biomenum[...]`, not `%%biomenum[...]%%` and the `set` command uses an `=` equal sign. Try: `if !biomenum[%%x][%%y]! LSS 0 set "biomenum[%%x][%%y]=0"`. Of course, you need to Enable Delayed Expansion before in order for this to work... The question title makes no sense: you are not using an `if` in an array, but in an _array element_.

Comment: Anyway, you not need to check for each number generated. You just need to generate the base variable between 1 and 14 via `set /A biomenum0x0y = %RANDOM% * 14 / 32768 + 1` because the rest of numbers are based on `biomenum0x0y` plus/minus one, _AND_ reset `biomenum[0][0]` to `biomenum0x0y` _after_ the nested FOR's...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code includes the modifications I suggested in my comments...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo Generating biomes...
rem The starting (center) biome
set /A biomenum0x0y = %RANDOM% * 14 / 32768 + 1
rem All biomes (including [0][0])
for %%x in (neg1 0 1) do (
   for %%y in (neg1 0 1) do (
      set /A nextbiomenum = !RANDOM! * 4 / 32768 - 1, biomenum[%%x][%%y] = biomenum0x0y + nextbiomenum %% 2
   )
)
rem biomenum[0][0] is the starting biome: reset it
set "biomenum[0][0]=%biomenum0x0y%"


echo %biomenum[neg1][neg1]% is the biome for -1,-1
echo %biomenum[neg1][0]% is the biome for -1, 0
echo %biomenum[neg1][1]% is the biome for -1, 1
echo %biomenum[0][neg1]% is the biome for 0, -1
echo %biomenum[0][0]% is the biome for 0, 0 -the starting chunk-
echo %biomenum[0][1]% is the biome for 0, 1
echo %biomenum[1][neg1]% is the biome for 1, -1
echo %biomenum[1][0]% is the biome for 1, 0
echo %biomenum[1][1]% is the biome for 1, 1
```